# Callback is not a function

Tags: nodejs, promesas, callback

Quiero crear un utilitario para imprimir desde NodeJS.

Tratando de sincronizarlo llegué al código que muestro más adelante, pero la corrida indica:

> `callback is not a function`

Es como si, a pesar de usarla con `await`, pretendiera evaluar el `callback`.

En algún momento separé ambas funciones (*create* y *toFile*) pero me daba el mismo error.

¿Tengo que pasarlas por el `promisify` a juro?

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Por cierto: a pesar de dar el error, la rutina funciona (escribe el `pdf` con el `html` enviado como contenido), el problema es que no llega al cliente, que se queda esperando la respuesta.

```js
// Módulo de Impresión para Node
var   impr;
async function imprime(texto,res) {
  let hora    = new Date();
  let nbRep   = "Asist_"+hora.getTime();
  let retorno = nbRep;

  if(!impr) {
    impr = require("./rogImpr.json");
    impr.pdf = require('html-pdf');
  }

  try {
    let salida = await impr.pdf.create(
      impr.cabecera + (typeof texto === "string" ? texto : texto.texto) + impr.pie,
      impr.prms
    ).toFile('./'+nbRep+'.pdf');
    retorno = salida.fileName;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    retorno = { fallo: true, msj: err.message }
  } finally {
    res.send(retorno)        
  }
}

exports.imprime = imprime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes tomar en cuenta que la librería [`html-pdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) tiene mucho tiempo sin ser actualizada (2 años a la fecha de esta respuesta). Por lo tanto te sugiero que busques alternativas, ya que esta librería presenta una [vulnerabilidad](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1095) severa.

No es necesario usar [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), a menos que desees que dicha utilidad se encargue de convertir una función que usa el antiguo sistema de [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) por ti.

Te mostraré la forma de hacer lo que necesitas usando tu propia función envoltorio que devuelve una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

En primer lugar debemos entender lo que sucede cuando se llama al método `create()`, para ello podemos ver el [código](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/blob/master/lib/index.js) de dicho método y darnos cuenta que devuelve un objeto.

Luego, este objeto tiene varios métodos (como podemos ver en su [código](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/blob/master/lib/pdf.js)), entre los cuales se encuentra el método `toFile()`, que usa una función `callback`.

Nuestro envoltorio usará el objeto devuelto por la función `create` y convertirá la respuesta del método `toFile` en una Promesa. Podríamos escribirlo algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
const pdfFile = (objPDF, path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    objPDF.toFile(path, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log(result); // { filename: 'ruta/nombre_archivo.pdf' }
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Esto sería la función que usaríamos para obtener el resultado del método `toFile` usando `async/await`, ya que la misma devuelve una Promesa.

Una forma de implementarlo en tu módulo:

```js
// Módulo de Impresión para Node

let impr; // no uses var, es preferible let o const

// declaramos nuestra función envoltorio
const pdfFile = (PDF, path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PDF.toFile(path, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

async function imprime(texto,res) {
  let hora    = new Date();
  let nbRep   = `Asist_${hora.getTime()}`; // es mejor usar string literals en vez de concatenar strings, es más intuitivo
  let retorno = nbRep;

  if(!impr) {
    impr = require("./rogImpr.json");
    impr.pdf = require('html-pdf');
  }

  // instanciamos el objeto PDF
  let pdfObj = await impr.pdf.create(
    impr.cabecera + (typeof texto === "string" ? texto : texto.texto) + impr.pie,
    impr.prms
  );

  // trabajamos con la Promesa
  try {
    let salida = await pdfFile(pdfObj, `./${nbRep}.pdf`); // devuelve una Promesa y podemos usar await
    retorno = salida.fileName;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    retorno = { fallo: true, msj: err.message }
  } finally {
    res.send(retorno)        
  }
}

exports.imprime = imprime;
```

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el Callback que va en el metodo toFile en esa linea:

`).toFile('./'+nbRep+'.pdf');`

En la documentación está un ejemplo:

```
pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});
```

[Documentacion de html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)

Comment: Ok: ¿Entonces el await va contra el create pero no contra el toFile?